# What is the first movie to show this hard work message at the very end?

Tags: first-appearance

What is the first movie to show this hard work message at the very end?

[image]

Comment: What movie is this message from? And by very end, you mean the very end of the closing credits?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is [Taken 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1397280/?ref_=nv_sr_1), released in 2012.

[image]

I didn't know about this message but I found the following article illuminating:

**[Fox kicks off campaign to educate consumers on economic impact of film and TV.](https://technology.ihs.com/416323/fox-kicks-off-campaign-to-educate-consumers-on-economic-impact-of-film-and-tv)**

> Fox has begun, with theatrical release of Taken 2, placing end cards on its movies with the message: "The making and legal distribution of this film supported over 14,000 American jobs and involved over 600,000 work hours." The implication is clear: illegal distribution through video piracy puts those jobs at risk.

Comment: Taken 2 had a budget of $45 million and Liam Neeson was paid $10 million...  but the college kid downloading the movie from his dorm room puts all that at risk

Comment: @gillonba Anti-piracy messages (or propaganda, depending on how appropriate you think such messages are) have been around for decades. Ever heard of "don't copy that floppy" or "home taping is killing music"?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen similar messages _before_ movies, and unless my memory is playing tricks on me, including _before_ this campaign.

Answer (score -4):

Actually i think first appeared on Blue Sky's Epic. It appeared ay the very end of every film from them until Spies in Disguise

Comment: You mean [this film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_(2013_film))? It was released in 2013, which is a year after the film mentioned in the other answer.