# When did credits start to show economical impact of the movie in the end credits?

Tags: production, credits

I watched *Alita Battle Angel* yesterday in a movie theater and I waited  until the end of the end credits to leave the theater. At the very end of it, after the *Special thanks* part, a sentence caught my eyes (approximative quote):

> 15,000 jobs were supported by the production of this movie.

If memory serves, it is the first time for me to see this part of the end credits.

**Is *Alita Battle Angel* the first movie to show this sentence (or a similar one) in its end credits? If so, why? If not, what is the first movie doing this?**

I usually quit the movie theater after the music credits, and ignore the *Special thanks* and production logos that appear at the very end of the credits.

Edit: while trying to find more information for my answer, I found out that my question is a duplicate of that [one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61974/what-is-the-first-movie-to-show-this-hard-work-message-at-the-very-end).

Comment: I haven't seen Alita Battle Angel, but I think a year ago I noticed movie studios including a segment at the beginning thanking viewers for supporting the film. I guess they're really worried about piracy.

Comment: No sooner than 2016, IIRC.  I'll have to do a little research to see if I can pinpoint it, but it's definitely a new phenomenon.

Comment: I think I saw this much earlier than 2016.  I think in one of the earlier MCU films, perhaps 2012-ish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the 20th century Fox started the practice in 2012 with *Taken 2*. This [article](https://technology.ihs.com/416323/fox-kicks-off-campaign-to-educate-consumers-on-economic-impact-of-film-and-tv) explains it is likely to inform the audience about the impact of illegal distribution and video piracy:

> Fox has begun, with theatrical release of Taken 2, placing end cards on its movies with the message: "The making and legal distribution of this film supported over 14,000 American jobs and involved over 600,000 work hours." The implication is clear: illegal distribution through video piracy puts those jobs at risk. Fox says it will include similar messages on the importance to the US economy of video production and distribution on all future releases, based on an idea voiced to the board of the Motion Picture Association of America (MPAA) by vice president Joe Biden at a meeting earlier this year.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen it before that on old VHS / DVD releases (not in the cinematic version) as an anti-piracy message (but I may just be imagining this!)